# Set .pdf name but prevent download with Rotativa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I need to set .pdf name before displaying it. I tried to set it like this

```
return new ViewAsPdf(GetViewName(), "", reportVM) 
{ 
   PageSize = Size.Letter, FileName = GetViewName() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".pdf"
 }; ,
```

but in this way the .pdf will be automatically downloaded. Is it possible to set the .pdf name and not downloading it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want pdf to displayed on the page? Instead of asking the user to save the file?

Comment: yes, I want to display it

Comment: You never can prevent it from being downloaded, if it displays in the browser, it was basically downloaded.

Comment: I understand, but without setting FileName I get the preview of the .pdf and the user could download it or not. All I want is to know if it is possible to set the file name and maintain that behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
var pdfResult = new Rotativa.PartialViewAsPdf("YourPartialView", model) {
    SaveOnServerPath = path, // Save your place
    PageWidth = 200,
    PageHeight = 350,
};

// This section allows you to save without downloading 

pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Answer (score 3):

After long research, the answer is no. The only thing that I could do is to set file name using response header and remove property FileName, so the code is now:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" +GetViewName() + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".pdf");
return new ViewAsPdf(GetViewName(), "", reportVM) { PageSize = Size.Letter };
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but that's the best I could get after all the reading. Hope it will help others too!

Comment: If you want to display a pdf, you could do it via an `<iframe>` or `<object>` however this will not guarantee to display on all of the users, since the browser itself should have a pdf plugin for it to preview the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

```
Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Margins margins = new Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Margins(10, 2, 5, 2); 
        return new ViewAsPdf(estimate)
        {
            CustomSwitches = "--viewport-size 1024x768",
            PageMargins = margins,
            FileName = "Estimate -" + estimate.EstimateNumber + ".pdf",
            ContentDisposition = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.ContentDisposition.Inline
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { Inline = true, FileName = "myCorrectlyNamed.pdf" }.ToString());
return new ViewAsPdf(GetViewName(), "", reportVM);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.